# How to configure bash to print exit status for every command?

Tags: bash

Every command run in bash returns with an exit code.

Whenever I type a command on bash prompt, I want it to show the exit status, i.e., `echo $?`

e.g., if I run `echo "hello";` on bash prompt, the output should be:

```
linux@linux$ hello
linux@linux$ 0
```

Comment: What about posting your question on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Thanks @Frank . But isnt it also a good place to put this question?

Comment: I tried print itas a part of PS1 variable, but does not work for reasons I don't understand yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exit code from the last executed command is stored in the `$?` environment variable. So you just can add this variable to the default command prompt and you will always have the exit code printed there. The prompt is stored in the `$PS1` environment variable. It is initially set in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` script and later in the `$HOME/.bashrc`.

So edit the line in `$HOME/.bashrc` (`/etc/bash.bashrc` would be system wide) from it's default value:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

to this (for example):

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w[$?] \$ '
```

So the default prompt in changed to:

```
user@host:/path/to/dir[0] $
```

The 0 in the brackets is your exit code, see:

```
user@host:~[0] $ ls
user@host:~[0] $ ls /root/
ls: cannot open directory /root/: Permission denied
user@host:~[2] $ ^C
user@host:~[130] $
```

For the meanings see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

Comment: I tried doing it but for the bash at hand, its not working. it always shows [0] for the machine I am working on.

Comment: Are you sure that you run a bash? Can you copy the output of `readlink /proc/$$/exe` please? 0 means no error, have you tried something that gives an error: `^C` or `false` or `asdasdasd`?

Comment: Got it done correctly. It was an issue with the quotes used to surround the PS1 variable. I had used double-quotes instead of single ones. Thanks for helping @chaos :)

Comment: @chaos I have my PS1 as `PS1=$(printf "%s\\\\u@\h:%s%s\w[$?]$%s " "$yellow" "$end" "$blue" "$end")`, but it just shows `0` all the time. Any idea why?

Comment: It would be nice, if the exit status would be only shown, if it is unequal 0

Comment: @max It's because your `$?` is already expanded to `0` when setting your `PS1`. Do `echo $PS1` and you'll see. You have to either use single quotes, or escape it like `\$?`.

Comment: @wisbucky Thanks, got an answer after 1.5 years. Love this site

Comment: Thank you from January 2018.  I really only want to see it if it is non-zero but this points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10):

Another way that I picked from [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Functions#Display_error_codes) was to use `trap`:

```
EC() { echo -e '\e[1;33m'code $?'\e[m\n'; }
trap EC ERR
```

Effect:

```
$ ( exit 1 )
code 1

$ some-non-existent-command
some-non-existent-command: command not found
code 127

$
```

Comment: That doesn't quite meet the OP's requirements, since he wants to print the exit status even if it's zero -- but it's *exactly* what I've been looking for.

Comment: Running the top code through [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) prints a couple of warnings: (1) This apostrophe terminated the single quoted string! (2) This word is outside of quotes. Did you intend to 'nest '"'single quotes'"' instead'?. If code is updated to: `echo -e "\e[1;33m code $? \e[m\n"` it solves the chellcheck warnings and still works exactly as intended.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example:

```
PS1='$? > '
```

If using double quotes, then you have to add a backslash to escape the `$`:

```
PS1="\$? > "
```

Output:

```
0 > echo 'ok'
ok
0 > bogus
bogus: command not found
127 >
```

---

An even better way is to only print the exit code when it is non-zero.

```
PS1='${?#0}> '    # single quote example
PS1="\${?#0}> "   # double quote example (requires extra backslash)
```

Sample output:

```
> echo 'ok'
ok
> bogus
bogus: command not found
127>
```

Explanation: `${var#pattern}` is a bash parameter expansion that means remove the shortest matching pattern from the front of $var. So in this case, we are removing `0` from the front of `$?`, which would effectively truncate an exit code of `0`.

If using double quotes, `$?` would be substituted when `PS1` is set, instead of being evaluated each time. Do `echo $PS1` to confirm you don't have a hardcoded value in `PS1`.

Comment: Thank you from January 2018. I want the normal prompt with the exit code at the beginning if it is non-zero - this helps a lot.