# Bash Script to search a webpage

Tags: bash, lubuntu, scripts

I've Googled my problem, and it's getting more confusing.

I want to write a bash script that will search [this](http://www.centennialcollege.ca/programs-courses/centres-institutes/applied-research-and-innovation/for-students/job-postings/) page for a specific string and echo if it's found. For example, if I wanted to search for the string "Game Developer", which exists on the page, it would echo "Found Game Developer!"

I'm not sure where to even begin. I'm using Lubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

The best I could come up with is this:

```
wget -q -O- http://www.centennialcollege.ca/programs-courses/centres-institutes/applied-research-and-innovation/for-students/job-postings/ | grep -c "Game Developer"
```

Comment: You might also want `-i` for `grep`, which ignores the case. Also, use the fact that `grep` returns 0 if a match was found and 1 if a match was not found.

Comment: it returns 1 if a match was found. I tested this same command before, and it worked.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - Is it possible to get the count? The number of times the string appears?

Comment: You already are, with `-c`. Also, in my previous comment, I didn't mean what would be printed out on `stdout`. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364190/configure-bash-to-print-exit-status-of-every-command-entered) question for what I mean, and see the Exit Status section in `man grep`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 - is there a way to print it though? Cause as you said, it only prints the exit status of grep.

Comment: You _are_ printing the count with `-c`; that's not the exit status. Try searching for "ame" instead of "Game Developer"; you should see that there are 12 occurrences of that string. See `man grep`.

Comment: Your command seems to already accomplish what you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I's switch to using grep's `-q` argument. This just exits with zero if it finds something. This allows you to use traditional exit-code logic like `&&` or `||` to chain on actions.

```
wget -qO- http://www.centennialcollege.ca/programs-courses/centres-institutes/applied-research-and-innovation/for-students/job-postings/ \
| grep -q "Game Developer" \
&& echo "Found Game Developer"
```

Only just read the comments. If you want the count, `-c` (as you've done) is as good as you'll get but if you do only need a boolean output, `-q` is faster as it exits 0 as soon as it first matches, rather than going on to find future matches.

If you want to capture and output the count, split it in two:

```
COUNT=$(wget -qO- http://www.centennialcollege.ca/programs-courses/centres-institutes/applied-research-and-innovation/for-students/job-postings/ | grep -c "Game Developer")
echo "Found $COUNT game developers"
```

Comment: It works! How can I print the number of times "Game Developer" occurs?

Comment: Can I capture the count in a variable?

Comment: And by that people here wrote your script. For the future I'd recommend reading the bash guides at http://www.tldp.org/guides.html