# What type of value do instructions return?

Tags: command-line, bash

Do instructions in linux have a return value? For example if we write `ls` we expect to see all the files and subdirectories of the current directory , however if we map `ls` to a function in `C` which would be the type of the return value `void` or something else?

Comment: Every process returns an 8-bit (0-255) "exit status" when it exits. A value of 0 usually means "success". Non-zero exit status indicates an error. The `errno -ls` will list the commonly used values. Programs may use their own values.

Answer (score 1):

It returns an integer *exit status* - just as a C entry point (`main` function) should:

```
$ ls -d ~testuser
/home/testuser
$ echo $?
0

$ ls -d ~nosuchuser
ls: cannot access '~nosuchuser': No such file or directory
$ echo $?
2
```

See also [How to configure bash to print exit status for every command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364190/how-to-configure-bash-to-print-exit-status-for-every-command)

Comment: So i cant use it as argument for a .sh file , yes?

Comment: @RootGroves I'm sorry, I don't understand what that means. Please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do.